# Ruby gem Xcodeproj throws exception on project save

Tags: ruby, xcode, xcode-project, xcodeproj

As I was experimenting with Xcodeproj I found an error that might come from misusing the API. Could you please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
require 'xcodeproj'

project = Xcodeproj::Project.new("test.xcodeproj")
new_target_name = 'test'
project.new_target(:framework, new_target_name, :ios)
project.save

target_to_remove = project.targets.select {|t| t.name == new_target_name}.first
project.targets.delete(target_to_remove)
project.save

target_to_remove.remove_from_project
```

This snippet gives me the following error message.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project/object/configuration_list.rb:101:in `ascii_plist_annotation': undefined method `isa' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:286:in `block in to_ascii_plist'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:285:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:285:in `to_ascii_plist'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:353:in `block in save'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:353:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.4.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:353:in `save'
    from /Users/testuser/Desktop/XcodeprojTest/test.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
targets_to_remove = project.targets.select { |target| target.name == new_target_name }
targets_to_remove.each { |target| target.remove_from_project }
```

I believe it's sufficient to just call `remove_from_project` for it to be removed, and for all references to be cleaned up properly.